# Find JSON object in JSON array

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a goal to verify that certain JSON that I've got from RabbitMQ corresponds to one of expected JSONs in an array in a single file.

In other words, I need to verify that this JSON:

```
{
  "networkCode":"network",
  "programId":"92000"
}
```

is present in this JSON array:

```
[
{
   "networkCode":"network",
   "programId":"92000"
},
{
   "networkCode":"network",
   "programId":"92666"
}
]
```

Thank you very much for help!

Some part of my code

```
//GET DESIRABLE JSON
String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            JSONObject myJSON= new JSONObject(message);

//GET THE JSON ARRAYS FROM FILE
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            Object expectedJSONs= parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\amqpclient\\src\\test\\java\\tradeDoubler\\ExpectedDTO.json"));
            JSONArray expectedArray = (JSONArray) expectedJSONs;

            JSONAssert.assertEquals(
                    myJSON, expectedArray , JSONCompareMode.LENIENT);
```

Compilation says that cannot resolve this

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Expecting a JSON array, but passing in a JSON object

Comment: Iterate over the array and check if the current object (in the array) equals the one you get from RabbitMQ

Comment: @Lino If I knew how, I'd do that and won't ask

Comment: I can just guide you to the [documentation](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/codehaus/jettison/json/JSONArray.html) as I wont write the code for you, especially the `getJSONObject()` and `length()` methods should help you to implement my suggestion from the other comment

Comment: What line does prompt the error? and what JSON library are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) library is quite easy to use.

Example code below:

```
import org.json.*;

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(" yourJSONObjectHere ");

JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("networkArray");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    String networkCode = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("networkCode");
    ......
}
```

By iterating on your JSONArray, you can check if each object is equal to your search.

You may find more examples from: [Parse JSON in Java](http://theoryapp.com/parse-json-in-java/)

Comment: Thank you! This was the most helpfull. But I had to use .size() instead of length().
And I compared JSONObjects, so I had to get a single object from an array :
JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(n);

and use this
JSONAssert.assertEquals("TEST FAILED", message, object.toJSONString(), JSONCompareMode.LENIENT);

Yes, I know that I could create a String and cast JsonArray item to String

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you to use the Gson Library?
You can use something like this. But It will throw an exception if the json doesn't match/contains the fields.

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YourJavaClassJsonModel>>() {
        }.getType();
        List<YourJavaClassJsonModel> resultList = gson.fromJson(JsonString, listType);
```

Hope it may help

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JSON parser to convert the JSON to a Java object ([Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) are good options), and then check that object.